# Is Core Data BLOB data encrypted when stored in "External Storage"?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, encryption

I'm using Core Data to store some sensitive information.  So far, I've applied hardware file encryption to the SQLite file used by the Persistent Store Coordinator.  I've done this by setting its file Attributes (NSFileProtectionKey to NSFileProtectionComplete).

I'm storing some image data as Binary Data in the Core Database and I've checked off the "Allows External Storage" and "Store in External Record File" to prevent bloating of my SQLite datastore and to improve performance.

I'm presuming that the data files automatically stored outside of the SQLite database by Core Data will NOT be encrypted and that I need to encrypt these files myself.  Does anyone know if this is correct?

Thanks

Comment: While not directly related, you should know the sqlite creates temporary files for transactions that are not encrypted, so if your app crashes while a database read/write is being performed the data will be available.

Comment: @HampusNilsson - hmmmm... something I hadn't considered.  Some food for thought.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

luckman777,

Every version preinstalled of iOS will hardware encrypt every file when the user uses a screen lock. With respect to your question about external Core Data storage, why don't you just look at the files? It is quite straightforward to move the data from the phone to your dev system. Then try to open one of the external files. I expect that it is encrypted. (If not, that is a rather big and obvious hole in Core Data's encryption policy. I doubt that it exists.)

Andrew

Comment: adonoho - thanks for the feedback.  I'm pretty sure though that hardware encryption is not automatic for all files.  This is why files such as the Persistent Store Coordinator require you to set its attribute to something other the NSFileProtectioNone value (the default).  Could you please tell me how to look at the files on the dev device if they're in the Library folder?  I can see the files no problem on my Mac if I am using the simulator.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: luckman777, your Xcode Organizer allows you to download all of the app's sandbox. Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Hidden, but **not encrypted**!
The folder it currently (iOS 11.2) holds the data is under *Documents/.SingleViewCoreData_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA*
There, you can see all the files, without their extension in a token-name. However, the data is all there unchanged. You can view any file by simply adding the file extension or using the right App.

Yes, the device data is encrypted when the screen is locked, but connected to Xcode, you can very easily download the container and access all the data. If your app holds sensitive data, the 'device is encrypted' will simply not hold. 
Only the `SingleViewCoreData.sqlite` file seems to be encrypted.